# Getting field value by class instance

Tags: c#, class, field, instance

I learn to write code in C# and I would like to know whether there is an option to get value of the field inside class just by using instance name. I would like it to look like that:

```
class foo{
   public Int32 field = 35;

   //Code i need... 
} 

public static void Main() {
   foo instance = new foo();
   Console.WriteLine(instance);
}
```

And the output would be "25". So is there any way to make such code to work or do I need to use for example property?

Comment: You should not use public fields. use properties instead.

Comment: What if you have multiple fields or properties? What should be printed then to console?

Comment: There won't be. My class has only one field and some methods.

Comment: If you wish to print all the properties of your class, you can override the `ToSpring()` method to do so. Then, `Console.WriteLine` will call such method and print what you want. Here is the documentation from Microsoft about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

Answer (score 3):

NO, there is not unless you specify the field or property you want to access saying `instance.field`. Though you can override the `ToString()` method to print that value like

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return field.ToString();
}
```

So now you can say

```
public static void Main() {
   foo instance = new foo();
   Console.WriteLine(instance); // will print 35
}
```

Comment: You do not need the call to `ToString()`, `Console.WriteLine()` has an overloaded version that takes an `object` and calls its `ToString()` method. Simply do `Console.WriteLine(instance);`.

Comment: You probably wanted to write ```field.ToString()```